# How to increase Godot render distance?

Tags: 3d, rendering, opengl-es2, godot-3, camera3d

I've tried changing the viewport far distance under `view > settings`, from 500 to 500 000 and nothing changes in game. The player can only see roughly 90-120 meters away.

It's not even about the camera zoom, because my camera can zoom from -150 to +150. By zooming all the way out  my character becomes invisible and so does everything below its feet.

[image: Draw distance screenshot]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you found out the Editor far distance can be changed in the Viewport Settings (which you access via View -> Settings...). But that is just for the editor.

For the running game, use the the `far` property in the `Camera`:

[image: Tool tip over the far property of Camera]